# Make a relation to a relation to a column in QSql

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qsqldatabase

I am trying to display an QSqlRelationalTableModel with a relation to a relation to a column.

This is my minimal code:

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlRelationalTableModel, QSqlRelation
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QAbstractItemView, QTreeView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSortFilterProxyModel
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

db = QSqlDatabase().addDatabase('QMYSQL')
[...]
db.open()

micTableModel = QSqlRelationalTableModel(None, db)
micTableModel.setTable('mic')
micTableModel.setRelation(1, QSqlRelation('equipmentgroup', 'id', 'name'))
micTableModel.setRelation(9, QSqlRelation('lending', 'id', 'XXX'))  #### <-- PROBLEM
micTableModel.select()

filterModel = QSortFilterProxyModel()
filterModel.setSourceModel(micTableModel)

widget = QTreeView()
widget.setModel(filterModel)
widget.setSortingEnabled(True)
widget.setRootIsDecorated(False)
widget.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The 9th column of `micTableModel` contains the key for an entry in the table 'lending'. 'lending' itself has a user_id, which is a relation to an entry in the table 'ldapuser'. And finally 'ldapuser' contains the 'username', which I would like to show in my `micTableModel`.

Any ideas how I could model such a relation in my micTableModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible to model hierarchic relations in QSqlRelationalTableModel. I think, You need all foreign keys in the parent table. But You could create a view in the database containing the lending.user_id additional to the fields of mic and use this view as table in `micTableModel.setTable(yourView)`:

```
create view yourView as
select m.*, l.user_id 
from mic m inner join lending l
on m.<name of field 9> = l.id
```

and set relation to ldapuser